# React - Slide out component on unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to slide out a React component when it umounts. I am using CSSTransition for the animation which works great for mounting, but not unmounting. Somehow I need to delay the unmount process. All the off-the-shelf solutions sadly do not work for me. I am removing an element by doing a post request and then actually removing it in the UI with a SignalR callback.

To make my sequence more clear, I created a sequence diagram:

[image]
This is my code right now:

**Board.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Config } from 'util/config';
import { container } from 'tsyringe';
import { AppState } from 'store';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { BoardState } from 'store/board/types';
import { BoardHubService } from 'services/hubs/boardHub.service';
import { BoardElementViewModel } from 'models/BoardElementViewModel';
import { BoardViewModel } from 'models/BoardViewModel';
import { BoardElement } from './boardElement/boardElement';
import { HttpService } from 'services/http.service';
import { setActiveBoard } from 'store/board/actions';

import './board.scss'
import { mapToType } from 'helpers/helpers';
import { TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

interface BoardProps {
    activeBoardState: BoardState;
    setActiveBoard: typeof setActiveBoard;
}

interface LocalBoardState {
    boardElements: Array<BoardElementViewModel>
}

class Board extends React.Component<BoardProps, LocalBoardState> {

    private config: Config;

    private httpService: HttpService;
    private boardHubService: BoardHubService;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.config = container.resolve(Config);
        this.boardHubService = container.resolve(BoardHubService);

        this.httpService = container.resolve(HttpService);

        this.state = {
            boardElements: []
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        // If there was any active board on page load...
        if (this.props.activeBoardState.boardId) {

            await this.loadBoardElements();
        }

        this.boardHubService.getConnection().on('SwitchedBoard', (response: BoardViewModel | null) => {
            console.log(response);

            this.setState({
                boardElements: (response) ? response.elements : []
            });

            this.updateSiteTitle(response);
        });

        this.boardHubService.getConnection().on('ReceiveElement', (response: BoardElementViewModel) => {

            let elements = this.state.boardElements;
            elements.unshift(response);

            this.setState(() => ({
                boardElements: elements
            }))
        });

        this.boardHubService.getConnection().on('RemoveElement', (response: string) => {

            let elements = this.state.boardElements;
            let element = mapToType<BoardElementViewModel>(elements.find(x => x.id === response));
            elements.splice(elements.indexOf(element), 1);

            this.setState(() => ({
                boardElements: elements
            }))
        });
    }

    /**
     * Load the elements from the board that was already active on page load.
     */
    private async loadBoardElements() {
        await this.httpService.getWithAuthorization<Array<BoardElementViewModel>>(`/boards/${this.props.activeBoardState.boardId}/elements`)
            .then((response: Array<BoardElementViewModel>) => {
                this.setState({
                    boardElements: response
                });
            })
            .catch((e) => console.warn(e));
    }

    private updateSiteTitle(board: BoardViewModel | null) {
        if (board != null) {
            document.title = `${board.name} | ${this.config.siteName}`;
        }
        else {
            document.title = this.config.siteName;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.props.activeBoardState.boardId != null
                    ?
                    <div className="board-elements">

                        {this.state.boardElements.map((element: BoardElementViewModel, index) => {
                            return (
                                <BoardElement
                                    key={index}
                                    id={element.id}
                                    // TODO: Use number from server
                                    number={element.elementNumber}
                                    user={element.user}
                                    direction={element.direction}
                                    note={element.note}
                                    imageId={element.imageId}
                                    createdAt={element.createdAt}
                                />
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>

                    :
                    <div className="select-board-instruction">
                        <h1>Please select or create a board.</h1>
                    </div>
                }

            </>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
    activeBoardState: state.activeBoard
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setActiveBoard })(Board);
```

**BoardElement.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { UserViewModel } from 'models/UserViewModel';
import { Direction } from 'models/Direction';

import './boardElement.scss';
import { dateToReadableString } from 'helpers/helpers';
import { Config } from 'util/config';
import { container } from 'tsyringe';
import { HttpService } from 'services/http.service';

import $ from 'jquery'
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

interface BoardElementProps {
    id: string;
    number: number;
    user: UserViewModel;
    // TODO: Use direction Enum
    direction?: Direction;
    note?: string;
    imageId?: string;
    createdAt: Date;
}

interface BoardElementState {
    show: boolean;
}

export class BoardElement extends React.Component<BoardElementProps, BoardElementState> {

    private config: Config;
    private httpService: HttpService;
    private ref: any;

    constructor(props: BoardElementProps) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            show: false,
        }

        this.config = container.resolve(Config);
        this.httpService = container.resolve(HttpService);
    }

    getReadableDirection(direction: Direction) {
        // TODO: Richtingen vertalen
        switch (direction) {
            case Direction.North: return 'Noord';
            case Direction.NorthEast: return 'Noordoost';
            case Direction.East: return 'Oost';
            case Direction.SouthEast: return 'Zuidoost';
            case Direction.South: return 'Zuid';
            case Direction.SouthWest: return 'Zuidwest';
            case Direction.West: return 'West';
            case Direction.NorthWest: return 'Noordwest';
        }
    }

    removeElement() {
        this.httpService.deleteWithAuthorization(`/boards/elements/${this.props.id}`).then(() => {

        }, (error) => {
            console.warn(error);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState(() => ({
                show: true
            }));
        }, 500);

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setState(() => ({
            show: false
        }));
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <CSSTransition in={this.state.show} timeout={200} classNames={{
                enter: 'animation-height',
                enterDone: 'animation-height',
                exit: ''
            }}>
                <div className="animation-wrapper animation-height-0" >
                    <div className="board-element" >
                        <div className="board-element-header">
                            <span className="board-element-number">{this.props.number}</span>
                            <span className="board-element-creator">{this.props.user.username}</span>
                            <i className="fas fa-trash ml-auto delete-icon" onClick={() => this.removeElement()}></i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="board-element-body">
                            {this.props.imageId
                                ? <img className="board-element-image" src={`${this.config.apiUrl}/content/${this.props.imageId}`} />
                                : <p className="board-element-message">{this.props.note}</p>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div className="board-element-footer">

                            {this.props.direction &&
                                <div className="board-element-direction">
                                    <i className="fas fa-location-arrow direction mr-2"></i>{this.getReadableDirection(this.props.direction)}
                                </div>
                            }

                            <time className="board-element-timestamp" dateTime={this.props.createdAt.toString()}>{dateToReadableString(this.props.createdAt)}</time>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </CSSTransition >
        )
    }
}
```

For better illustration take a look at this GIF:
https://gyazo.com/3c933851ecec39029f25d4df3a136c2a

That is using jQuery in another project of mine. That is what I want to achive in React.

Answer (score 1):

You can delay unmounting the component. Write a `hoc` and use a `setTimeout`. Maintain a state say `shouldRender`.

**hoc**

```js
function delayUnmounting(Component) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    state = {
      shouldRender: this.props.isMounted
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (prevProps.isMounted && !this.props.isMounted) {
        setTimeout(
          () => this.setState({ shouldRender: false }),
          this.props.delayTime
        );
      } else if (!prevProps.isMounted && this.props.isMounted) {
        this.setState({ shouldRender: true });
      }
    }

    render() {
      return this.state.shouldRender ? <Component {...this.props} /> : null;
    }
  };
}
```

**usage**

```js
function Box(props) {
  return (
    <BoxWrapper isMounted={props.isMounted} delay={props.delay}>
      ✨✨✨✨✨
    </BoxWrapper>
  );
}

const DelayedComponent = delayUnmounting(Box);
```

**See complete code in the demo**

[image: Edit delay unmount]

[Read this article on medium](https://medium.com/@tomaszferens/delay-unmounting-of-the-component-in-react-8d6f6e73cdc)

Comment: This did not work for me. I've tried this already and tried it again just now, but it again did not work. I am using classes and not functions.